# How to pass a reserved keyword as a prop in reason-react

Tags: syntax, keyword, reason, bucklescript, reason-react

I am trying to use the [rimble-ui](https://rimble.consensys.design) ui-library, and one of the props that a button takes is called "as". This is unfortunately a reserved word in reason. So I don't know how to use this component in my reason-react app.

[Here](https://rimble.consensys.design/components/rimble-ui/Button) are the docs for the library.

[image: Eample from docs]

This is my code:

```
[@bs.module "rimble-ui"] [@react.component]
external make:
  (~as_: string, ~href: string, ~target: string, ~children: React.element) =>
  React.element =
  "Button";
```

And my [reference](https://reasonml.github.io/reason-react/docs/en/components#import-from-js) for importing to reason-react from js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BuckleScript removes a prefixed underscore character from reserved words when compiling to JavaScript, so you can name the prop `_as` and it will work:

```ml
module Test = {
  [@bs.module "rimble-ui"] [@react.component]
  external make:
    (~_as: string, ~href: string, ~target: string, ~children: React.element) =>
    React.element =
    "Button";
};

let test = <Test _as="" href="" target="">{React.string("")}</Test>;
```